# Simple Paths Along Vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, summation

Let $v$ and $w$ be distinct vertices in $K_n$, $n\geq 2$. Show that the number of simple paths from $v$ to $w$ is
$$(n-2)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{k!}.$$

A path with no repeated vertices is called a [*simple path*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29).

Comment: What have you tried? It's better if you show some of your work, or whatever you have attempted, and people would be more likely to answer your questions.

Comment: If you count the paths (sequences of vertices really) you get a formula like this. So what is the question?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen the OP is asking why this is what you get - how do you count them...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

- You work in a clique $K_n$, so the edges are not a problem (you can go between any two vertices you want).
- With fixed $v$ and $w$ (the path's beginning and ending), there are $(n-2)!$ possible permutations of vertices.
- There are paths of different lenghts, and for a path that does *not* use $k$ vertices (i.e. paths of $n-k$ vertices), you don't care about the order of those skipped $k$ vertices, that is, there are $\frac{(n-2)!}{k!}$ such paths.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

For each $i$, there are $\frac{(n - 2)!}{(n - 2 - i)!}$ paths of length $i$ (Where length denotes the number of inner vertices in the path, here.)

This can be shown by considering a path of length $i$ starting at $v$.

Clearly, its next vertex must be one of the $n - 2$ vertices not $v$ or $w$, and similarly, the vertex after that must be one of the $n - 3$ other vertices, and so on for the next $i$ vertices.

Thus, there are $(n - 2)(n - 3)\dots((n - 2) - i + 1) = \frac{(n - 2)!}{(n - 2 - i)!}$ paths of length $i$ for each $i$.

Now, summing this from $i = 0$ to $i = n - 2$ (Because you can't have a path of length less than 0, and the longest possible $v-w$ path in this graph would be of length $n - 2$) gives a similar summation to the one that you have: $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 2} \frac{(n - 2)!}{(n - 2 - i)!} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 2} \frac{(n - 2)!}{i!} = (n - 2)! \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 2} \frac{1}{i!}$.

Note: The summation given in the question is incorrect.

For example, consider $K_3$ with two arbitrary vertices.

Clearly, there are two paths between them -- the direct one and the one through the third vertex.

However, the summation in the question gives that there are $(3 - 2)! \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{1} \frac{1}{k!} = 1 * 1 = 1$ paths, as it discounts the path containing $0$ inner vertices.

Comment: Are all your expressions correct?

Comment: Particularly the expression $(n - 2)(n - 1)\dots((n - 2) - i + 1)$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was thinking of it the other way around. It's fixed now.

Comment: What is the $1$ for?

Comment: The $(n - 2)$ term is the first term, and can be written as $(n - 2 - 0)$. The $(n - 3)$ term is the second term, and can be written as $(n - 2 - 1)$. The last term is $(n - 2 - i + 1) = (n - 2 - (i - 1))$, and, following the pattern from before, is the $i$th term, as the term $(n - 2 - k)$ is the $k + 1$th term for any $k$.